# Control mulitple AnythingSliders with one nav

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I'm using AnythingSlider, http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/, and have created a page which contains 2 sliders.

Is it possible to control both these sliders with the prev/next arrows of only one of them? i.e you click the 'prev' arrow of slider1 and slider2 also moves to the previous slide.

I have this working using a function in the onSlideBegin callback, and passing the targetPage to the other slider ($slider):

```
$imgSlider = $('#imgSlider').anythingSlider({
    onSlideBegin: function(e, slider) {
        $slider.anythingSlider(slider.targetPage);
    }
});
```

The problem is when moving from the first slide to the last (or last to first). The slider that the arrows belong to behaves as desired (the slider is infinite, so moving from first to last uses the cloned slides). But the other slider rewinds through all slides.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

When you tell AnythingSlider to go to a specific page, it will just go directly there and not slide through the cloned slides. [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/rWjrU/791/) is from the [home wiki](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/wiki) page that has one set of arrows controlling both sliders.

```
$('#slider1, #slider2').anythingSlider({

    // If true, builds the forwards and backwards buttons
    buildArrows: false

});

$('#fwd, #bck').click(function(){
    var direction = (this.id === 'fwd') ? 'goForward' : 'goBack';
    $('ul[id^=slider]').each(function(){
        $(this).data('AnythingSlider')[direction]();
    });
});​
```